# the sign of a real function

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, graphing-functions

Let us define:

$$P(m)=96 m^8 - 2112 m^7 + 19392m^6-79872 m^5 + 117600 m^4 +17472 m^3 -162432 m^2+99072 m-9216$$

for

$$m \in \mathbb{R}$$

How can I show that: $P(m)>0 $ for $ m \geq 9 $.

PS: Please note that I have already drawn the graph of $P$ with "MAPLE" and it gives  what I want to proof.

Comment: thank you  for your correction

Comment: Where does this polynomial come from? Any known root or factor?

Comment: so i dont know anything about the root of this polynome, but it's comes frome the lower bound of the ratios of bessel functions

Comment: Possibly you could divide all coefficients by $96$ first...?

Comment: yes , and after ? i think you want to apply the enestrom kakeya theorem

Comment: You may also try to find rational roots and decompose the polynomial by dividing it by $(x-root)$ for each root found. The reduced polynomial may appear easier to handle...

Comment: thank you i was thinkig you want to have the order of the coeefecient before m^8.... and you want to apply the enestrom Kakeya theorem , but i thnik without numerical factorisation it's so hard to study the root of this polynomial functions

Answer (score 0):

If you show it is positive for a value $m>9$ and then show that all $9$ roots are $\le 9$ then the values cannot proceed below the vertical axis.

Comment: thank you for the answer but i dont think we are able to solve an equation of degree 8 ,

Answer (score 0):

As a polynomial of degree $8$ with a positive leading coefficient, we know that it opens up towards the positive y-axis after its last root is achieved.

Note that

$$P(m) = 96 (m - 1)^2 (m - 2) (m^5 - 18 m^4 + 125 m^3 - 240 m^2 - 396 m + 48)$$

The irreducible polynomial of degree $5$ has roots that can be numerically confirmed to have the following approximate values:

$$x=-1.09834$$ $$x=0.113819$$ $$x=5.53445$$ $$x = 6.72504 + 4.91435 i$$ $$x = 6.72504 - 4.91435 i$$

And the largest of these roots is less than $9$, hence $P(m) > 0$ for $x \geq 9$.

(In fact, $P(m) > 0$ for $x > 5.54$)

Comment: great , thnak you . you use "maple" to factor this polynom?

Comment: @abla I used Wolfram|Alpha, but I imagine that Maple would have this same functionality.

Comment: I am a little weak in numeric    so  we can study easly the graph of $ (m^5 - 18 m^4 + 125 m^3 - 240 m^2 - 396 m + 48)$ and it's  give the answer without approximation of the roots ,thank you agan

Comment: It is not possible to acquire the exact roots, if that's what you're asking. Numerical approximation is quite necessary.

Comment: yes but we can study the graph of  $(m^5 - 18 m^4 + 125 m^3 - 240 m^2 - 396 m + 48)$ and it's give as the answers about the sign of $P$

Comment: @abla I'm not sure what you're asking. Its roots give us information about the P, but not necessarily its sign. We need to use all of P's roots to determine its sign. My answer lists those roots. Like with any degree-8 polynomial with a positive leading coefficient, the function is positive to the right of the largest root.

Comment: no your answer is correct , but using the factorisations that you gave, we can easly know the sign of $P$ without using the numerical roots 
but it's clear with the factoring it becomes an easy question

Answer (score 0):

i have use a numerical method, here are all roots in an approximative form
$$-2.15533752664163, 0.0277005296499047-0.0662778779440053i, 0.0277005296499047+0.0662778779440053i, 1.21497451131535-3.57762045136675i, 1.21497451131535+3.57762045136675i, 6.94587700876063-5.43061456034008i, 6.94587700876063+5.43061456034008i, 7.77823342718986$$

Comment: thank you ,but w need just real roots , thank you so much

Comment: I don't think these are the correct roots

Comment: why not? this polynimial can not be factorized

Comment: $P(1) = P(2) = 0$, so this cannot be the correct set of zeros.